# angular js accordian unable to toggle tab in function

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js accordion to expand collapse tabs:

Following I am using to change accordion:

```
$scope.accordionOpen.final = true;
```

It works well in controller too, but when I put it inside a controller it stops working

```
            paymill.createToken(params, function(error, result){                    
                $scope.accordionOpen.final = true;
            });
```

**$scope.accordionOpen.final = true;** is inside controller only,

can anyone help me to solve accordion issue

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it should be inside `$scope.$apply`

Comment: Where is it "outside of controller"?

Comment: No its inside controller

Comment: Thanks $scope.$apply() worked. but it would be great if u can give specific reason why it won't work